# Why can't curl download the ffmpeg-2.7.tar.bz2?

Tags: curl, ffmpeg

I'm working on OS X Yosemite 10.10.2. I want to use curl command to download the ffmpeg-2.7.tar.bz2 as following:

> curl -O http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.7.tar.bz2

It can't work.

However it works fine with other url.

The message as following when add the **--verbose** option:

```
$ curl --verbose -O http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.7.tar.bz2
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 192.190.173.55...
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to ffmpeg.org (192.190.173.55) port 80 (#0)
> GET /releases/ffmpeg-2.7.tar.bz2 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: ffmpeg.org
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 302 Found
< Location: http://211.167.105.70:80/1Q2W3E4R5T6Y7U8I9O0P1Z2X3C4V5B/ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.7.tar.bz2
< Connection: Close
< 
{ [data not shown]
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
```

**Where did I go wrong?**

PS:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.37.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0) libcurl/7.37.1 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? What happens if you run `curl --verbose -O http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.7.tar.bz2` ?

Comment: @TachyonVortex I got the message: "Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache".

Comment: When using `--verbose`, do you get the message: `Trying 192.190.173.55` ? Do you see any HTTP headers, like: `> GET /releases/ffmpeg-2.7.tar.bz2 HTTP/1.1` and `< HTTP/1.1 200 OK` ? Do you get any other error messages? Please provide as much information as possible. Also, please take a look at the excellent article: [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) (especially the section: ["My ... doesn't work"](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idp64791344)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using a proxy (`211.167.105.70:80`), which is returning a [302 redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).

To make curl follow HTTP redirects, use the [`--location`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L) option:

```
curl --verbose --location -O http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.7.tar.bz2
```